# How should I really use QLocalSocket and QLocalServer?

Tags: qt, ipc, named-pipes

Qt example about using QLocalSocket/QLocalServer for IPC is not that clear as it should be.

I have arrived (after a lot of what-if ideas) to next conclusions:

1. **Sockets for windows named pipes are designed to deliver one message at a time.** It can not be used in continuous for never-ending data stream as pipe stores all data sent inside regardless if it was read or not causing huge memory waste. So basic use-case looks like: reciever connects to pipe -> sender sends one frame of data -> someone of them close socket hanlde until reciever wants more (and again new connection must be established)
2. **QLocalSocket cannot be saved as instance.** This is confusing. First connection is done perfectly. I create a receiver class with QLocalSocket within. I connect this socket to named pipe and read data. I close the socket (on the sender side) and connect it again to the pipe to read next data frame. Server sees the new connection, but once I try to write into - "Socket is closing" error appears. Looks like some data is remaining (may be `HANDLE` to windows socket is saved from previous connection).
   With Process Explorer I've found that socket is connected only within my function inside class (slot with only `connectToServer' function), but once control is returned to Qt event loop - connection to named pipe disappears before server has any possibility to write into it. Once again: this happens only second time, if the socket has ever been closed. If I delete socket and create new one (on the heap) - it works like it should.
3. **There are some problems with detection if QLocalSocket is valid while one side is closed unexpectedly.**
   This happens when I force close receiver executable after connection has been established. Server has already stored pointer to socket but it is no more valid. Looks like `isValid()` or other methods from QLocalSocket could help me, but they fail too. In practice when client is forced closed QLocalSocket instance on sender side still exists, but has messed up private implementation: in `qiodevice.cpp : 1607` where `CHECK_WRITABLE(write, qint64(-1));` is performed `d_ptr` is not valid pointer anymore and has something like 0xafafafaf. Looks like private implementation is controlled outside Qt event loop causing this to happen.

So. After all said. It looks like I am doing something wrong. So how do QLocalSocket should really be used for never-ending data stream in cases when client must receive data as soon as it exists?

**UPD:** please find code example [here](https://github.com/BilyakA/SO_43875664). Also note `socket_by_instance` branch to understand my second note.

Some notes about the code: Let's say I have some data stream incoming on once every 10 ms that I must process on the sender side (in any case) and sent it to receiver(s) if it(they) exists.

What I do not like in this code is that on the receiver side I need to do `new`/`deleteLater` for every socket connection (100 times per second). Knowing that receiver always has one connection and it is always opened and always connected to one the same socket - I think this is waste of time doing `new`/`delete` here. Please look at `socket_by_instance` branch to see my try to avoid this issue.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you *showed* your code rather than describing it.

Comment: **I close the socket and connect it again...** - Why are you doing this and why would you want a socket (which is an asynchronous mechanism) on the stack?

Comment: @G.M. please see my UPD to question. I've added some code example

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I am sorry, I have mistaken with terms. I meant socket "saved by instance" but not "saved on the stack.". I've updated my question to make it clearer.